# How to make nested maps of variable depth

Tags: c++, dictionary, nested, stdmap

I want to be able to create an std::map with a value that is another std::map and I want to to be able to nest this map to an arbitrary depth.

Here is a basic example:

```
std::map < std::string, std::map < std::string, int> > d1;

//       so the next depth would be.

std::map < std::string, std::map < std::string, std::map < std::string, int> > > d2;
```

I know this is simple to do for fix length but am unsure of how to approach building one of variable depth.

Comment: Could you show an example of how such a class would be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we cant specialize `using`, we have to go the old way with `class` + `typedef` and expose it with `using` in the end:

```
template<typename Key, typename Value, unsigned int N>
struct VarMapHelper
{
    typedef std::map<Key, typename VarMapHelper<Key, Value, N-1>::type> type;
};

template<typename Key, typename Value>
struct VarMapHelper<Key, Value, 1>
{
    typedef std::map<Key, Value> type;
};

template<typename Key, typename Value, unsigned int N>
using VarMap = typename VarMapHelper<Key, Value, N>::type;
```

---

Use it like:

```
VarMap<std::string, int, 3> map;
```

---

To prevent a compiler crash if one misuses the class as `VarMap<std::string, int, 0>` we can provide a specialization for 0 aswell:

```
template<typename Key, typename Value>
struct VarMapHelper<Key, Value, 0>
{
    static_assert(false, "Passing variable depth '0' to VarMap is illegal");
};
```

Comment: The last specialization for ```N=0``` seems to be ill-formed, and is triggered on compilation. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52137187/static-assert-in-template-specialization-fails-even-if-it-is-not-instantiated).