# Static assert in template specialization fails even if it is not instantiated

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, template-specialization, static-assert

The following code compiles fine:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T> struct dependent_true : std::true_type { };
template <typename T> struct dependent_false : std::false_type { };

template <bool B = false>
class X { static_assert(dependent_false<X>::value); };

template <>
class X<true> { static_assert(dependent_true<X>::value); };

int main() {
   X<true> x;
}
```

That is, the `static_assert` in the primary template is not evaluated. On the contrary, if I switch to:

```
template <bool B = false>
class X { static_assert(dependent_true<X>::value); };

template <>
class X<true> { static_assert(dependent_false<X>::value); };

int main() {
    X<false> x;
}
```

Then, the static assertion in template specialization fails, even if it is not instantiated. **I just wonder why.** I observed this behavior with GCC 8 and Clang 6 (`-std=c++17`).

Live demo: https://wandbox.org/permlink/MOWNLnGMgmuDA2Ht

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`template <> class X<true> {/* ... */};` - is not a template anymore.

> [[temp.expl.spec]/5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.expl.spec#5)
>
> A member of an explicitly specialized class is not implicitly
>   instantiated from the member declaration of the class template;
>   instead, the member of the class template specialization shall itself
>   be explicitly defined if its definition is required. In this case, the
>   definition of the class template explicit specialization shall be in
>   scope at the point at which the member is defined. **The definition of
>   an explicitly specialized class is unrelated to the definition of a
>   generated specialization**. That is, its members need not have the same
>   names, types, etc. as the members of a generated specialization.
>   **Members of an explicitly specialized class template are defined in the
>   same manner as members of normal classes, and not using the template<>
>   syntax.** The same is true when defining a member of an explicitly
>   specialized member class. However, template<> is used in defining a
>   member of an explicitly specialized member class template that is
>   specialized as a class template.

The specialization is just like a regular class. It's not a template, and nothing is dependent. Therefore `dependent_false<X>::value` is just a constant expression that evaluates immediately to false. So the static assertion is immediately triggered.

Answer (score 1):

Even non-instantiated template parts should be valid C++ code. `static_assert(false)` makes the program ill-formed. So you have your specialization with `static_assert` which is known on compile time to be `false` and your program becomes ill-formed. You have no non-resolved template parameters on your class which is used in `static_assert` to make compiler wonder; it knows exactly that it is `false`.

The same goes to `if constexpr`, you also can't use `static_assert` with expressions known to be false even if the part where this `static_assert` is located always gets discarded.