# Why is this template class specialization being instantiated?

Tags: c++, template-specialization, template-instantiation

Inside a specialization for a templated class I call a function which should not compile, but in my mind it shouldn't matter as I pass `false` as a template argument and the compiler shouldn't instantiate that class in the first place:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
struct outerstruct
{
    template <bool b>
    struct innerStruct
    {
    };
    template<>
    struct innerStruct<true>
    {
        using type = std::underlying_type_t<T>;
    };
    template<>
    struct innerStruct<false>
    {
    };
    
    
    innerStruct<false> member; // std::underlying_type_t cannot be called on a T,
                               // even though that class shouldn't be instantiated
                               // because I'm passing false (or I think)
};

int main()
{
    outerstruct<int> a;
}
```

Why is `innerStruct<true>` being instantiated and the compiler trying to call `underlying_type` if I pass the `false` argument?

Very confusingly for me, I can make it behave the way I want (ie., have the compiler ignore the call to `std::underlying_type_t`) by just adding another template argument to `innerClass`, here I add a `U`:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
struct outerstruct
{
    template <typename ExtraArg, bool b>
    struct innerStruct
    {
    };
    template<typename ExtraArg>
    struct innerStruct<ExtraArg, true>
    {
        using type = std::underlying_type_t<T>;
    };
    template<typename ExtraArg>
    struct innerStruct<ExtraArg, false>
    {
        
    };
    
    //innerStruct<bValue> member;
    innerStruct<int, true> member;  // Now it's working as I expected,
                                    // I can pass int or whatever argument to ExtraArg
                                    // and it compiles as long as I have 'false'
};

int main()
{
    outerstruct<int> a;
}
```

What is the difference between the first and the second examples? What business does template specialization `innerStruct<true>` have being instantiated if in the first example I only called `innerStruct<false>`

Comment: It is instantiated because you declare a fully specialised class template. In the second example you declare only partially specialised class templates.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Static assert in template specialization fails even if it is not instantiated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52137187/static-assert-in-template-specialization-fails-even-if-it-is-not-instantiated)

Comment: Templates are just factories that produce class definitions. The rule of thumb is that whenever all template parameters are known, it's no longer a template, but the product of the factory. If you fully specialize, you are just defining a regular class with some additional syntax.